# Finding End Of SQLite File In Disk Dump?

Tags: sqlite, io, binary

This is really stumping me. I'm trying to recover some lost information (for reasons I cannot disclose) from a dump of an Android phone's free space. I have no lookup table for the disk, so all I have is the raw dump of the flash.

Basically, I'm trying to pick out SQLite files from this huge 350 megabyte mess. I can find the SQLite file header easy enough, it's 100 bytes and described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html). Everything seems to be in place. However, I can find entries, but I'm currently stumped as to how to determine where the entries stop and the file ends and other sectors of the disk are filled.

Any suggestions? I'm at a dead end currently, other than kind of manually going through and trying to eyeball it, but I'm a programmer here, trying to find some sort of methodical way through this.

I appreciate you guys in advance!

Comment: I just used a hex browser to examine a SQLite file, and I didn't find anything -- the data just ends.  I'm pretty sure, though, that there is some sort of per-page header that must conform to some minimal set of restrictions (where pages are on the order of 2K in size, alas varying with the install parameters).

Comment: (The source is online and not terribly difficult to read, so you can probably find a description of the page header.)

Comment: Oh, yeah. I mean, I can pick out the 100 byte header easy, the problem is determining where the entries end.

Comment: SQLite maintains its data in fixed-length pages.  If you can identify a page start (and know the page size) you know where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had luck recovering data using PhotoRec which, despite its name, supports many file formats including sqlite.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec

I've never tried it on a dump of flash memory so I don't know how successful it would be. It depends on how the file is layed out in memory and PhotoRec bets on the fact that most files are stored in contiguous blocks (i.e. not fragmented).